# JBoss 6.2 EAP - Multiple war DataSource Performance

Tags: performance, jboss

I have WebAppA using H2 in-memory database.

When WebAppA is deployed alone I get query times of about 300ms for 2k entities.

When WebAppA is deployed with WebAppB (HSQL file database) query times take 3x longer (1000 ms for 2k entities).

This occurs without any interaction with WebAppB. I also tried stripping WebAppB from any DataSource persistence but get the same results.

Hibernate debug logs are identical with just WebAppA deployed and WebAppA and WebAppB deployed.

Any ideas on why the performance hit? Is there extra configuration that can address this?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out WebAppB was packaged with a log4j.properties which set org.hibernate logging to DEBUG, causing the increase in execution times.